# save file record with "extendable-media-recorder" typescripts

Tags: typescript, audio, record, audio-recording

I learned to record here [extendable-media-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extendable-media-recorder) but don't know how to save the recorded file to the local file by the path, can someone help me answer my question. thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljAgN.png)

Answer (score 0):

This example it will you provide help

example link : https://jsfiddle.net/r490zs7j/

```js
var audioChunks;
startRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = true;
  stopRecord.disabled=false;
  // This will prompt for permission if not allowed earlier
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
    .then(stream => {
      audioChunks = []; 
      rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive"){
          let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
          recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          recordedAudio.controls=true;
          recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
          audioDownload.href = recordedAudio.src;
          audioDownload.download = 'mp3';
          audioDownload.innerHTML = 'download';
       }
      }
    rec.start();  
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));
}
stopRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = false;
  stopRecord.disabled=true;
  rec.stop();
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
        <h2>Audio record and playback</h2>
        <p>
            <button id=startRecord>start</button>
            <button id=stopRecord disabled>stop</button>
        </p>    
        <p>
            <audio id=recordedAudio></audio>
            <a id=audioDownload></a>
        </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you, but i'm using typescripts

Comment: you can easily convert PureJs to Typescript based events only writing approach how to achieve this, if you like my answer mark as Correct it is very appreciable for engineers

Comment: @ahii1289 kindly give us correct mark or up mark to motivate our community